# Ubuntu Black Screen on Resume-After-Lid-Close

Tags: drivers, suspend, intel-graphics

I've been struggling with this one for a while. I have my ASUS K55A Laptop set to "no hibernate to disk" only "suspend to RAM". However, after I close the laptop lid, I still get a black screen. The weird thing is sometimes, after a hard reboot, on the first resume-after-lid-close it DOES resume, however on the second resume-after-lid-close I get a black screen. Also, there are times when I have a YouTube movie playing, and on a resume-after-lid-close which gives me a black screen I can hear the YouTube video playing ("behind" the black screen).

Asus K55A Laptop
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Gnome

.---------------.

```
tom@Toms-Laptop-K55A:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3839       3733        105        138        170        913
-/+ buffers/cache:       2649       1189
Swap:         3909          0       3909
```

.---------------.

When did CTRL + ALT + F1 I got a login prompt. I entered username and password, and then received the appropriate user prompt. Then I did CTRL + ALT + F7 and was presented with the Black Screen.

It's a Black Screen with a Glow, and if I press Fn-F7 (screen off) the glow shuts off.
This is the same as when I Reboot and Login, I then see that glowing-black-screen, and then the purplish Gnome Desktop appears.

Since it's a glowing-black-screen that tells me the screen is not off, it is on and "showing me" a black or blank image.
.---------------.

Graphics Card
lspci | http VGA
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
.---------------.

- tom@Toms-Laptop-K55A:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test --print
  OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
  OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile
  OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.1.3
  Not software rendered:    yes
  Not blacklisted:          yes
  GLX fbconfig:             yes
  GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
  GL npot or rect textures: yes
  GL vertex program:        yes
  GL fragment program:      yes
  GL vertex buffer object:  yes
  GL framebuffer object:    yes
  GL version is 1.4+:       yes
  Unity 3D supported:       yes
  .---------------.

tom@Toms-Laptop-K55A:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for tom:
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 09
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:47 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff   ioport:f000(size=64)
.---------------.

X.org log file pasted here
http://pastebin.com/Yze9P1Rt
.---------------.

pm-suspend.log. pasted here 
http://pastebin.com/w20SZ3N2
.---------------.

These links seem like they would be helpful, but they're a bit beyond my technical ability.
https:// 01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/development/how-debug-suspend-resume-issues
https:// www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt
.---------------.

Is it significant that it's a Black Screen with a Glow, and if I press Fn-F7 (screen off) the glow shuts off?
.---------------.

Pastebin Diagnostic Files:

1. X.org log file pasted here
   http://pastebin.com/Yze9P1Rt
2. pm-suspend.log. pasted here http://pastebin.com/w20SZ3N2
3. Output of: sudo systool -m i915 -av
   http://pastebin.com/X3YKB7zW y
   .---------------.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Ubuntu's support for suspend/sleep/other low-power modes is rather hit-or-miss. When I first installed Ubuntu, my custom desktop would suspend just fine, but it wouldn't come out of it to a functional desktop. Some time after rebuilding my system with new hardware, it started working. If I recall correctly, Ubuntu 14.04 is what made it so my computer would suspend and resume correctly. However, on my work computer, an HP Compaq something-or-other also running Ubuntu 14.04, I haven't had any luck with suspend.

Basically, in my experience, Ubuntu sometimes has trouble correctly interfacing with a computer's hardware when it comes to sleeping and resuming. It is completely possible that there is a way to fix such compatibility issues, but I don't know enough to generate a solution, and I may not know enough to comfortably implement such a solution. Unfortunately, that's the best answer I can give, but it's totally possible that some Linux guru may see your problem and come up with a solution.

Comment: Do you think this could fix the problem?

Workaround A: Non-graphical Boot
You can disable the graphical bootscreen via:
    "set gfxpayload=text" 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen

How would I do that?
Does that make a non-graphical boot, or a non-graphical session (like without the Ubuntu Gnome graphical user interace)?

Comment: That article seems to be talking about a different problem. One of the non-symptoms listed is when it occurs when closing a laptop's lid, suggesting the [PipeA Quirk](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Quirks#Force_Pipe_A_Quirk) as a more likely possibility. However, something that I have thought of since my initial answer would be to check your BIOS low-power settings. It could be that changing the low-power state in the BIOS might improve compatibility with suspending from Ubuntu. I haven't messed around with such settings, so I'm afraid I may not be very helpful beyond here.

Comment: I've vote this because it clarifies my nebulous suspicions. My Dell laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 has a quite chaotic behaviour after closing the lid and lifting it back later. Sometimes, there is a black screen, sometimes, there isn't. And sometimes, the black screen is so stubborn, that, no matter what keys I press, no matter how long I hover the cursor on the screen, no mater what I do and how long I wait, the black screen is still there and the only way to get read of it is to just press the power button and restart the PC.

Answer (score 0):

It's very late but people can still have the problem. You might have come across a way of fixing related to the **#HandleLidSwitch=suspend**. If nothing else worked and you have Nvidia drivers installed, uninstall them.

To do it:

1. Press *Show Applications* (3x3 matrix) --> type *NVIDIA* --> *PRIME PROFILES* (last option) --> And select the gpu not related to NVIDIA.

[image: Image here]